# How to determine if landscape orientation is a regular horizontalSizeClass?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uikit, uisplitviewcontroller

I’m trying to get a custom storyboard just for iPad and Max/Plus devices, but not there for smaller devices (which I would load a different storyboard).

I can simply check if the device is in landscape and the `horizontalSizeClass` is regular like this:

```
UIScreen.main.traitCollection.horizontalSizeClass == .regular
    && UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape
```

However, this only works if the device is in landscape mode. If the device is in portrait, I don't know how to check if its landscape orientation is a regular `horizontalSizeClass` (even though the device is still in portrait mode).

[image]

Is there a way to determine the size class for a specified orientation?

Comment: `UISplitViewController` does this automatically. You don't need to check. You don't need different code or different storyboards.

Comment: But it’s loading the splitview in the Xs device. I don’t need a master, just a detail there. I guess it’s not really like the Settings app. Updating the question.

Comment: On smaller devices, the split view ends up working just like a nav controller with two (or one) initial view controllers.

Comment: Right, and I can hide the display button as well, but I’m wondering if this would be unnecessary overhead for devices that don’t need it.